# Не работает import discord

Tags: python, discord.py

При импорте подчеркивает зеленой линией и пишет: Файл сохранен в кодировке "Кириллица (Windows)", которая не соответствует кодировке UTF-8 по умолчанию

Comment: Приложите код, как вы импортируете ```discord.py``` или код ошибки, чтобы бы легче понять, где ошибка

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Изменить кодировку фала можно через "Сохранить как"